# simulating a domain user logon on machine startup

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, domain

I'm currently working on a lab for AD penetration testing and want some of the machines to have a logon, including the TGT, for a specific domain user cached. So far I couldn't come up with anything better than using the Winlogon feature. The drawback of this is that the password is hardcoded in the registry, which defeats the point of passing-the-ticket. Is there a better way to do this?